# Derive both MAC and AES keys from same PBKDF2?

Tags: encryption, aes, mac, key-derivation, pbkdf-2

When doing password-based encryption, is it OK to create one instance of **PBKDF2** from the password, and then use it to create both the **AES** key and the **MAC** key? (Or should a new instance of PBKDF2 be created using a different salt or iteration count, for each?)

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6468/1131)   seems to say this isn't a good idea. While [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1489/1131)   seems to say it is. Am I misunderstanding one of them? (Or both.)

<sub>(And by the way, the first is marked as a duplicate of a question which deals with an initially strong key, while it itself deals with a simple passphrase.)</sub>

Comment: You should avoid deriving more than the natural output size direclty PBKDF2. With PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA512 that's enough for two keys, with *-SHA1 it isn't. If you need more key material, use HKDF-Expand on the output of PBKDF2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos From the second link: `PBKDF2 supports the generation of arbitrary amounts of key data`. (I'm using [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if it matters.)

Comment: It can, but when you do it might be possible for the attacker to compute it more cheaply than for the defender, since the defender needs the whole output, whereas the attacker might be able to confirm it with only part of the output. This shouldn't happen with well designed password based key derivation functions, but PBKDF2 is not one of those.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks. Is there any **.net** implementation of HKDF (or better yet, of a `well designed password based key derivation functions`)?

Comment: Implementing HKDF-Expand on top of HMAC is pretty easy.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm searching it now, but can't seem to find anything less technical than [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869) (or just general descriptions like ["is a simple HMAC-based KDF..."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function#Uses_of_KDFs).

Comment: I just remembered that I actually implemented HKDF in C# a couple of months ago: https://gist.github.com/CodesInChaos/8710228

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks. I just now finished writing my own using the [specs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869) and am looking for test vectors. But I only wrote the **Expand** so the test vectors that are available don't help me. Perhaps I'll write the **Extract** as well. It looks from your code like that's the simple part.

Comment: Actually they do help you. Simply use `PRK`, `info` and `L` as input and check if `OKM` matches. But extract is a one liner, simply call `HMAC(salt, ikm)`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos But anyway - as I wrote in my comments to my new question - now I don't understand why was HKDF-Expand invented at all (since one can simply use any hash). And also: You can convert your comments to answers, as they have been helpful and deserve upvotes. **EDIT** Thanks for the previous comment. I'll have to try that now.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Do you base your recommendation (not to derive more than the natural output size directly from PBKDF2) primarily on considerations of performance with some impact on security by way of allowing less iterations for a given effort, as pointed in [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13228/555); or do you have some other consideration in mind?

Comment: Consider scrypt instead of PBKDF2, it handles this very well. There is no “natural output size,” AFAIK. If you want two 256-bit keys, use 512 as the length argument and use bits 0-255 and 256-511 as the two keys.

Comment: @fgrieu I mainly base it on performance, i.e. on the issue describes in that answer. I also think that being able to specify an arbitrary `info` string is nice.

Answer (score 3):

From a security point of view, deriving lots of key material using PBKDF2 is ok.

From a practical point of view, deriving lots of key material using PBKDF2 is inefficient (in the sense that to generate $n$ blocks and increase the adversary's work by $t$, you do work $nt$, instead of $n+t$).

A more practical solution uses PBKDF2 to generate a short string and a suitable generator (probably HMAC-based) to produce lots of key material. Typically:
$$k_0 \leftarrow PBKDF2(pw, \dots)$$
$$\text{key material} \leftarrow HMAC(k_0, 1) || HMAC(k_0, 2) || HMAC(k_0, 3) || ...$$

Comment: Generally we try and use a KBKDF such as HKDF instead of a HMAC to generate the additional key material, although HMAC with a counter comes pretty close.

Comment: **Deriving lots of key material from PBKDF2 is _not_ OK—it can _hurt_ security.**  Why?  If you draw $n$ blocks of PBKDF2 output, the adversary's cost to find the key can be as little as $1/n$ times what it would have been had you generated one block and fed it through (say) HKDF.  In [some cases](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59511) it may not hurt, but these cases have to be analyzed in excruciating detail individually, so it is better to just generate one block and use HKDF to work around this stupid design in PBKDF2.